# Error in eigen(val, only.values = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x' when estimating lambda in gls

Tags: r, lambda, estimation

I have problems estimating lambda using the gls function in R.

The gls function works perfectly fine when I am running it with a fixed value of lambda (ie.  fixed=TRUE) but when I am trying to estimate lambda and incorporate this estimation of lambda into my analysis, ie. :

```
result = gls(traitY ~ traitX, data=DF, 
             correlation=corPagel(value=1, tree_list[[1]], fixed=FALSE), method="ML")
```

I always get the following error message :

```
Error in eigen(val, only.values = TRUE) : 
  infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

My question is : to what does eigen refer to in my data / what is x in my following data (data=DF) ?

```
DF

                    traitY    traitX               
Alouatta_palliata           0.5273489 0.6250000
Ateles_geoffroyi            0.5051398 0.4380000
Cebus_capucinus             0.2895715 0.5036667
Saimiri_sciureus            0.3591358 0.6590000
Cebus_apella                0.6884629 0.5572500
Cercopithecus_diana         0.5714286 0.9050000
Chlorocebus_pygerythrus     0.7604781 0.7246667
Erythrocebus_patas          0.0000000 1.0000000
Macaca_arctoides            0.4155720 0.5895000
Macaca_fuscata              0.6594206 0.5563333
Macaca_mulatta              0.6614815 0.8275000
Macaca_nigra                0.6416667 0.8170000
Macaca_radiata              0.7331135 0.6910000
Macaca_tonkeana             0.4991048 0.8932500
Papio_ursinus               0.7044067 0.6570000
Homo_sapiens                0.5037506 0.5320000
Pan_paniscus                0.6000000 0.9000000
Pan_troglodytes_troglodytes 0.1771352 0.8856364
Pongo_pygmaeus              0.5000000 0.6000000
Eulemur_fulvus_fulvus       0.7662338 0.8730000
Eulemur_fulvus_rufus        0.7334606 0.5475000
```

PS. I am using the libraries : `nlme` and `ape`

I would be really thankful for any kind of suggestion/help since I can ‘t continue my analysis without solving this particular problem (it is really important to get the estimted lambda for my statistical interpretation) and have been stuck for quite a while and haven’ t found anything useful on the net.

Thanks in advance,
Ly

Comment: Could you just try `result = gls(traitY ~ traitX, data=DF)` first ? If it works, the problem comes from `tree_list[[1]]`. The error comes from functions used by the `nlme` package's developper. `eigen` is a function used to develop `gls` function which calculates eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a given `x` matrix.

Comment: Thanks! Now I at least know where the problem is coming from, since the code does work when I use the code for result the way you proposed.
This means the problem comes from tree_list[[1]] and since the dataset (tree data) is provided from the 10k tress website, there is no way (since I don’t have access to their formulars) that I will ever be able to calculate an estimated lambda value, no ?